# Recorrer un ListBox y meter sus items en un array

Tags: c#, string

Relleno una lista desde un `OpenFileDialog` y lo meto en "file" para después meterlo en la lista así:

```
foreach (string file in selectedFiles)
{
    ListBoxItem lstItem = new ListBoxItem();
    lstItem.Content = file; //File es la cadena de la URL
    miLista.Items.Add(lstItem);
}
```

Lo que asigno al `ListBox` son `URL` tipo

**c:\user\paco\imagen1.jpg**

**c:\user\paco\imagen2.jpg**

Todo bien hasta aquí, pero ahora necesito recorrer ese `ListBox` y meter sus Item en un `String[]`

```
String[] matriz = new String[miLista.Items.Count];
foreach (Object index in miLista.Items)
{
    matriz = index.ToString().Split();
}
```

De este modo lo que me mete en cada indice del `string[]` es lo siguiente:

**System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem: c:\user\pepino\imagen1.jpg
System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem: c:\user\pepino\imagen2.jpg
System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem: c:\user\pepino\imagen3.jpg**

Lo que yo necesito es sólo la `URL` y que no me devuelva el Tipo y el Valor, necesito meter en el `String[]` sólo el valor.

Relleno el `ListBox` así:

```
OpenFileDialog myFD = new OpenFileDialog();
myFD.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
myFD.Multiselect = true;
myFD.Title = "Seleccione uno o más archivos";
myFD.Filter = "Archivos imagen (*.jpg),(*.jpeg),(*.gif),(*.png)|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png";

Nullable<bool> result = myFD.ShowDialog();
if (result == true)
{
    string[] selectedFiles = myFD.FileNames; // La propiedad FileNames (o FileName) almacena la ruta, nombre y extensión.
    foreach (string file in selectedFiles)
    {
        miLista.Items.Add(file);               
    }
    archivo.set_listaReproduccion(selectedFiles);
    archivo.grabar();
}
```

Comment: ¿Ay alguna manera de hacer el arreglo bidimensional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema que tienes es en esta porción de código:

```
foreach (string file in selectedFiles)
{
    ListBoxItem lstItem = new ListBoxItem();
    lstItem.Content = file; //File es la cadena de la URL
    //aqui estas agregando un ListBoxItem a Items cuando solo deberías agregar file
    miLista.Items.Add(lstItem); 
}
```

Una solución sería reemplazar esta línea y utilizar las sugerencias que te dimos antes:

```
 miLista.Items.Add(lstItem);
```

Por

```
 miLista.Items.Add(file);
```

Pero si necesitas que `lstItem` siga dentro de la colección `listbox.Items` entonces lo que tienes que hacer es un casteo.

```
String[] matriz = new String[miLista.Items.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < miLista.Items.Count; i++)
{
    ListBoxItem item = miLista.Items[i] as ListBoxItem;
    if(item!= null)
    {
        //suponiendo que content es un string
        matriz[i] = miLista.Items[i].Content;
    }

}
```

---

Suponiendo que cargas tu listbox de esta manera, no deberías tener problemas de casteo:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            foreach (var item in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }

        String[] matriz = new String[listBox1.Items.Count];

        listBox1.Items.CopyTo(matriz, 0);
    }
```

Fíjate que `FileNames` ya es un `String[]` prácticamente no necesitas hacer ni el `copy` ni el `for` solamente asignarlo:

```
String[] matriz = openfiledialog.Filenames;
```

Pero de todas maneras voy a dejar mas abajo formas de hacerlo así le pueda servir a otras personas.

---

La opción mas sencilla es:

```
listBox1.Items.CopyTo(matriz, 0);
```

Pero también puedes hacerlo utilizando un ciclo `for` en vez del `foreach`

```
String[] matriz = new String[miLista.Items.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    matriz[i] = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Tu primer ejemplo lo había probado ya, y me devuelvo lo mismo que con el foreach. Y en tu segundo ejemplo me devuelve el error:  **Al menos un elemento de la matriz de origen no se puede convertir en la matriz de destino.**

Comment: @FranPino mira este código lo probé y funciona en Framework 3.5, que estás utilizando ?

Comment: podrías aclarar en tu pregunta, como se cargar esos items a tu listbox ? contiene solo strings, o algún otro dato de otro tipo ?

Comment: @Alan, en la pregunta se dice que es a traves de un `OpenFileDialog` con multiselect.

Comment: entonces no deberías tener problemas de casteo. puedes mostrar esa parte de tu código ?  me refiero  a como se lo agregas al listbox.Items

Comment: @Alan podría enseñarme como tienes el código?? Uso el Framwork 4.5

Comment: @FranPino dame un segundo, voy a intentar replicar tu caso con un openfiledialog.

Comment: he editado el post agregando como relleno el listbox

Comment: ahora veo porque tienes ese problema. ya edito mi post

Comment: @FranPino editado

Comment: @Alan, podrias explicarme cuál es el problema para poder entenderlo?

Comment: editado, espero que no haya quedado muy confuso.

Comment: @Alan muchas gracias ya está solucionado. y gracias a ti tambien NaCI me has ayudado. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Puedes intentar usando:

```
foreach (string file in selectedFiles)
{
    miLista.Items.Add(file); 
    // No es necesaria la instancia de ListBoxItem ya que puedes agregar
    // objects de cualquier tipo.
}
```

Y luego:

```
string[] Matriz = miLista.Items.Cast<string>().ToArray();
// Asignas el valor directamente.
```

Con esto directamente tienes un array de `string` con todos los valores.

**EDIT:** Aclaro que `Cast<string>()` no debería ser necesario ya que estamos agregando items de tipo `string` a lista.

Si no te funciona lo anterior, puedes probar a combinar la respuesta de Alan y esta:

```
string[] Matriz = new string[miLista.Items.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < miLista.Items.Count; i++)
    Matriz[i] = miLista.Items[i].ToString();
```

Este se supone que debe funcionar, dado que tienes elementos del tipo string dentro de `ListBox.Items`

> En caso de que ninguna te funcione, tienes un arreglo de strings en el `OpenFileDialog` que es `FileNames` que ya es de tipo `string[]` solo deberias hacer esto:

```
string[] Matriz = ofd.FileNames; // donde ofd es tu OpenFileDialog.
foreach (string s in Matriz)
    miLista.Items.Add(s); // Agrega al listbox los elementos de la Matriz.
```

A veces el orden de las instrucciones puede estar mal, pero puede funcionar de cualquier forma.

[Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115275/cast-listx-to-listy) te dejo la respuesta de SO de donde encontré algo parecido, saludos!

Comment: Gracias no sabía que podría quitar el ListBoxItem, esa parte funciona ok. Tu última linea me devuelve el error: ** No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem' al tipo 'System.String'.**

Comment: Pues, creo que puedes combinar ambas respuestas, o bien quitar el `.Cast<string>()` y dejarlo: `string[] Matriz = miLista.Items.ToArray();`

Comment: la gran pregunta es, tu listbox solo tiene strings o tiene algún otro tipo?

Comment: también es importante de que manera agregas tus items a ese listbox.

Comment: @NaCI gracias por todo.